# GnU GPL v2 DHTMLX ASP.net C# - How to read data from data base (JSON) returned by a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, scheduler, dhtmlx

I read that I can do something like this

```
scheduler.parse([
     { start_date:"2013-05-13 6:00", end_date:"2009-05-13 8:00", text:"Event 1"},
     { start_date:"2013-06-09 6:00", end_date:"2009-06-09 8:00", text:"Event 2"}
],"json");
```

on http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_parse.html

but I dont want to manually place all data, I want it to read data from my database

so what I did is that I have this method on Data.ashx

```
public string getJson(int ID)
        {
            XXXContext db = new XXXContext();
            var YYYY = db.Y.Where(p => p.YYYID == ID).Include(p => p.ZZZZ).ToList();
            List<CalendarEvent> cEvent = new List<CalendarEvent>();

            foreach (var evnt in YYYYY)
            {
                cEvent.Add(new CalendarEvent() { id = evnt.AAAAID, text = evnt.PPPPP.FirstName.ToString() + " " + evnt.PPPPP.MiddleName.ToString() + " " +  evnt.PPPPP.LastName.ToString() + "<br />" +
                    evnt.Reason.ToString() + "<br />" + evnt.Details.ToString(), start_date = evnt.XXXXXDateTime??DateTime.Now, end_date = evnt.XXXXXDateTime??DateTime.Now });
            }
            IEnumerable<CalendarEvent> toIEnum = cEvent;

            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(toIEnum);
            return json;
        }
```

This returns a JSON formatted output

but i dont know what to do next<

this is what i got on my html file, which I called using IFrame on my aspx class

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function init() {
        scheduler.config.multi_day = true;

        scheduler.config.xml_date="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
        scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2015,0,10),"week");
        scheduler.load("../../Data.ashx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify data format in arguments of [scheduler.load](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_load.html), otherwise it would expect xml by default:

```
scheduler.load("../../Data.ashx", "json");
```

Also note that the client side will expect start_date/end_date dates to be serialized in the format specified in [scheduler.config.xml_date](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_xml_date_config.html) config (**"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"** according to your code) while JavaScriptSerializer will stringify DateTime into something following:

```
"start_date": "/Date(1355496152000)/"
```

there are a couple of possible workarounds, for example, you can override a method that parses dates and parse them manually:

```
scheduler.templates.xml_date = function (dateString) {
    var timestamp = dateString.substring(6, dateString.length - 2);
    return new Date(timestamp * 1);
};

scheduler.load("../../Data.ashx", "json");
```